# Which works faster Null coalesce , Ternary or If Statement

Tags: c#, .net, null-coalescing-operator

We use [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to evaluate expressions against null values, for example:

```
string foo = null;
string bar = "woooo";
string foobar= foo ?? bar ; 
// Evaluates foobar as woooo
```

We also used an `if` statement, which works the same if used with above expression

```
string foo = null;
string bar = "woooo";
if(foo==null)
   string foobar=   "woooo" ;
// Evaluates foobar as woooo same as above
```

And also [?: Ternary Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)...

```
string foo = null;
string bar = "woooo";    
string foobar= foo==null ? "woooo" : null ;
// Evaluates foobar as woooo same as above
```

I know that null coalescing is precise in syntax, but which one is compiled faster among both and performs more faster and why?

Comment: its more like syntactic sugar ..

Comment: If you're that concerned about runtime, C# might not be your best bet.

Comment: Technically, you should be comparing `??` to `?:` not to `if` as `?:` is much more a closer logical fit to `??` than `if` is.

Comment: If this is causing a performance problem for you code, you have much bigger concerns.

Comment: @Servy No, performance wise i found them same..but i was thinking why was the need of the exact alternate..i know its syntactically more precise then if..i just wanted to know the best answer of using the both statement in diff way that's it...

Comment: @MayankPathak You should only concern yourself with the performance of some block of code when you've demonstrated that you are having a problem involving that construct or method.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: The second code example is _not_ the same as the first! If `foo` is not `null`, the first example will assign `foo` to `foobar`. Your second example doesn't.

Comment: @comecme It's worse then that: `Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement`

Comment: Odd that this was closed as "not a real question", seemed like a good question to me.  I do think "performance first" is typically the wrong strategy, but it's still a valid question in my book.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543522/why-do-we-prefer-to-operator-in-c

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may be asking the wrong question.  You don't choose to use one over the other primarily due to efficiency (though it may be a secondary concern), but due to utility.

Really you should compare `??` to `?:` and not to `if` as they have different purposes.  Yes, they are all some form of "conditional" goodness, but the key is that both `??` and `?:` evaluate to a value, whereas `if` does not, thus they often have different uses.

For example, the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("The order} is for {1} product",
    orderId, productId ?? "every");
```

Would be clunkier to write with an `if`:

```
if (productId == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The order {0} is for every product",
        orderId);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The order {0} is for {1} product",
        orderId, productId);
}
```

Yes, you could condense to one, but then you'd have a temp variable, etc:

```
if (productId == null)
{
    productId = "every";
}

Console.WriteLine("The order {0} is for {1} product",
    orderId, productId);
```

Thus really, you shouldn't compare the two, because they point of the `??` is to evaluate to a value if the argument is `null`, whereas the point of `if` is to execute a different path (not directly resulting in a value.

So, a better question may be, why not this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("The order {0} is for {1} product",
    orderId, productId == null ? "every" : productId);
```

Which is much the same (both evaluate to a value) and are not as much for flow control.

So, let's look at the difference.  Let's write this code three ways:

```
// Way 1 with if
string foo = null;
string folder = foo;

if (folder == null)
{
    folder = "bar";
}

// Way 2 with ? :
string foo2 = null;
var folder2 = foo2 != null ? foo2 : "bar";

// Way 3 with ??
string foo3 = null;
var folder3 = foo3 ?? "bar";
```

For the IF, we get the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     
IL_0004:  ldnull      
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0008:  ceq         
IL_000A:  stloc.1     
IL_000B:  ldloc.1     
IL_000C:  brtrue.s    IL_0016
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ldstr       "bar"
IL_0014:  stloc.0
```

For the conditional (? :) we get the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     
IL_0004:  brtrue.s    IL_000D
IL_0006:  ldstr       "bar"
IL_000B:  br.s        IL_000E
IL_000D:  ldloc.0     
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  stloc.1
```

For the null-coallescing (??) we get this IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     
IL_0004:  dup         
IL_0005:  brtrue.s    IL_000D
IL_0007:  pop         
IL_0008:  ldstr       "bar"
IL_000D:  stloc.1
```

Notice how each successive one is simpler?  The `if` is larger IL because it needs branching logic to handle the separate statements.  The `?:` is smaller because it simply evaluates to a value (not branching to other statements) but still needs to load the operand to compare to (`null`).

The `??` is the simplest of all, because there is an IL instruction for comparing to `null` (vs loading `null` and comparing to it.

**SO** all of this said, you're talking a very small difference in terms of IL, which may or may not affect performance.  Regardless, chances are this will have **very** little major difference compared to more intensive work in the program (math, database, network, etc.).

Thus, I would suggest choose the one that is the *most* readable, and only optimize if you find through profiling that your current method is inadequate and a bottleneck.

To me, the real reason to use `?:` or `??` is when you want the end result to be a value.  That is, anytime you'd be tempted to write:

```
if (someCondition)
    x = value1;
else 
    x = value2;
```

Then I'd use the conditional (`?:`) because that is what it is a great shorthand for.  `x` gets one or the other value based on this condition...

Then I'd go one further with `??` and say the same is true, you want to assign a value to a variable based on the `null`-ness of an identiifer.

So `if` is great for flow-control, but if you are just returning one of two values or assigning one of two values based on a condition, I'd use `?:` or `??` as appropriate.

*Finally* keep in mind how these things are implemented under the covers (IL and the associated performance) are subject to change with each revision of the .NET Framework (as of me writing this right now they are all so close to be negligible).

Thus, what may be faster today may not be faster tomorrow.  So again, I'd just say go with the one that fits best and you find most readable.

**UPDATE**

Incidentally, for the truly obsessed, I compared 10,000,000 iterations of each code swatch above, and here's the total time to execute each.  Looks like `??` is fastest for me, but again these are *so* close to be almost inconsequential...

```
10,000,000 iterations of:
?: took: 489 ms, 4.89E-06 ms/item.
?? took: 458 ms, 4.58E-06 ms/item.
if took: 641 ms, 6.41E-06 ms/item.
```

Comment: i had to assign `foobar` to some value as i mentioned in above examples..thus i used `if` in my scenario. using ternary i didn't found suitable..

Comment: way1 and way3 are the same (the C# code)

Comment: sorry, cut and paste error, corrected...

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Very Detailed Answer, thanks it really helped.. :) +1 and accepting it as answer..

Comment: And i'm updating my question as well, as according to your answer it will be more helpful.. :)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, in C# 8.0 we have more specific ones for the null condition-based assignment by ??=

Answer (score 6):

<strike>They should both compile to the same IL, and thus execute the same.</strike>

Even if they didn't, the performance difference would be negligible. I wouldn't even think to look at this unless I profiled my application and saw the statements taking a significant amount of time.

Always use the clearest syntax unless you can prove it's causing a performance problem, not before.

Comment: I agree with the part about using the clearest syntax, but the `??` operator actually does compile to less IL.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare - Really? That's surprising. Unfortunately I don't have something in front of me I can look at...what's the difference?

Comment: @JustinNiessner http://pastebin.com/DqXqk3Nm  (With optimizations disabled)

Comment: @asawyer - Any chance you could also post the IL for a method that takes a parameter rather than defining everything statically? Looks like the compiler might have optimized that IL.

Comment: @JustinNiessner How's this look:  http://pastebin.com/F1wHfQNM