# parameter with default object value

Tags: c#, default-parameters

I have a class and function

```
class A
{
    A(int i = 0)
    {
    }
}

void f(A a = new A(10)) // ? default parameter value must be compiler-time constanct
{
}
```

How to workaround it?

Comment: If my answer below solved your issue please indicate so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do it inside the method and provide a comment that the method accepts null and uses `A(10)` as a default value.

```
void f(A a = null)
{
    if(a == null)
        a = new A(10);
}
```

Comment: <cough> null coalescing operator </cough>

Comment: @Slugart That wouldn't work because the assignment only needs to be made if the object is `null`. You could use `a = a ?? new A(10);` but there is no need.

Comment: ?? is the null coalescing operator.  There is no need but it is neater and more concise, right?

Comment: @Slugart If the parameter is not `null` it will do the assignment still. It is an operation that doesn't need to happen. By doing the null check the assignment will only happen if a null is passed; or in this case by default.

Comment: Fortunately the c# and CLR teams thought of this and there's an IL instruction for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385503/which-works-faster-null-coalesce-ternary-or-if-statement

Comment: @Slugart That answer only addresses assigning a _different_ variable a value based on the first; not assigning the first based on the first.